# reputation leagues are not working

Tags: bug, status-completed

At the Users page, the following link does not work:

[weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/68/week/writers)

I know it hasn't been a week yet, but it could be functional.

Comment: Let's give it some time and try again.  I know the one for Gaming lags behind current events, so it's probably something that's calculated pretty infrequently.

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't yet have sufficient data, as @StrixVaria said.